# mode hooks and eval-after-load

Tags: key-bindings, hooks, scheme

I am trying to set up some keybindings for working with scheme. I have these two mode hooks which contain the bindings I want:

```el
(add-hook 'scheme-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key (kbd "C-j") 'scheme-send-last-sexp)))

(add-hook 'scheme-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-j") 'scheme-send-region)))
```

The problem is that I also have these hooks defined which I use for elisp:

```el
(eval-after-load "paredit"
  #'(define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "C-j") 'eval-last-sexp))

(eval-after-load "paredit"
  #'(define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-j") 'eval-region))
```

My question is: how can I modify eval-after-load to set up my scheme key bindings only when in Scheme mode?

Comment: If you only use those paredit bindings for elisp, then they should be written like your scheme bindings but using the `emacs-lisp-mode-hook` or `lisp-interaction-mode-hook`.

Comment: @JordonBiondo I occasionally use them for Clojure too.

Comment: Write a function that locally creates bindings and add it to every major mode hook you want to use them in. That is the standard way to do it.

Comment: @JordonBiondo how is that different from the lambdas in the add-hook calls above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by unwinding paredit's keybindings first, then setting up my mode-hooks.

```
;; clear paredit bindings paredit mode
(eval-after-load "paredit"
  #'(define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "C-j") nil))

(eval-after-load "paredit"
  #'(define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-j") nil))

(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-j") 'eval-region)
             (local-set-key (kbd "C-j") 'eval-last-sexp)))

(add-hook 'racket-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (paredit-mode)
             (local-set-key (kbd "C-j") 'racket-send-last-sexp)
             (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-j") 'racket-send-region)
             (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-s") 'racket-repl)
             (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-p") 'clipboard-yank)
             ))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you mean *set up only my scheme key bindings* instead of "*set up my scheme bindings only*". Otherwise, if you do mean set up the scheme bindings only in Scheme mode then that should already be happening.
2. If `paredit-mode` is a minor mode and `scheme-mode` is a major mode then you can't. A minor-mode keymap takes precedence over a major-mode keymap (aka local map).

   You can put one or the other command on a different key. But if you put both commands on the same key then the minor-mode binding wins.